# Transform Mathematica formula into ExcelForm for copy and paste to Excel cell

Tags: excel

What I need is a function ExcelForm[expression] which transforms a given expression into a form, which I could just copy and paste into an Excel cell.

Just like TeXForm[expression] does for TeX.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32374425/4251542

Comment: p.s. isn't `CForm` enough?